# How can I install python or python packages with a specific PyUnicode?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, fftw, python-unicode

I am trying to install [PyFFTW](https://github.com/hgomersall/pyFFTW) a pythonic wrapper for [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/). When I do so I get the following error.

> ImportError:
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so :
>   undefined symbol : PyUnicodeUCS2_FromUnicode

Vaarious websites suggest that when this problem occurs to either install python with the correct PyUnicode or to install the python package with the correct PyUnicode. I have no idea how to do either of these. Can someone please provide me with a step-by-step guide on how to do this?

I am installing the PyFFTW package using sudo pip install pyfftw on a RaspberryPi.

Thanks, 
E.Lee

Comment: http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/Got-quot-undefined-symbol-PyUnicodeUCS2-FromUnicode-quot-error-td18721.html Is one such website whose help I tried to follow, without success.

Comment: As the author of pyFFTW, I'm really interested to know if you got this to work. Presumably you're using the ARM version of FFTW?